# How to use a sql function (coalesce or isnull) in Simple.Data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, simple.data

I am porting a sql query to Simple.Data, the original query is something like:

```
select a.Field1, a.Field2, b.Field1
from TableA a
join TableB b ON a.KeyField = b.KeyField
where coalesce(b.SomeDate, '1/1/1900') <= getdate()
```

I've been able to port everything in the query except for that darn coalesce logic:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var result = db.TableA.Query()
    .Join(db.TableB).On(db.TableA.KeyField == db.TableB.KeyField &&
        db.TableB.SomeDate == currentDate)
    .Select(db.TableA.Field1, db.TableA.Field2, db.TableB.Field1);
```

Any thoughts on how to get the coalesce behavior in there?  I've tried using the `??` operator to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When there is a SQL function which takes a column name as its first parameter, you can specify it as a method on the column:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var defaultDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
var result = db.TableA.Query()
    .Join(db.TableB).On(db.TableA.KeyField == db.TableB.KeyField &&
        db.TableB.SomeDate.Coalesce(defaultDate) <= currentDate)
    .Select(db.TableA.Field1, db.TableA.Field2, db.TableB.Field1);
```

Note that if you have referential integrity set up between TableA and TableB, you can leave out the explicit join and simplify this query to:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var defaultDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
var result = db.TableA
    .Query(db.TableA.TableB.SomeDate.Coalesce(defaultDate) <= currentDate)
    .Select(db.TableA.Field1, db.TableA.Field2, db.TableB.Field1);
```

Comment: @MarkRendle how to use cast function for eg. cast(col_abc as integer)

Comment: @PavanJaju Not possible, unfortunately. I'll look into it for v2.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `Simple.Data` before, but I think you want to do this:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var nullDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
var result = db.TableA.Query()
    .Join(db.TableB).On(db.TableA.KeyField == db.TableB.KeyField &&
        ((!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, db.TableB.SomeDate) ? db.TableB.SomeDate : nullDate) <= currentDate)
    .Select(db.TableA.Field1, db.TableA.Field2, db.TableB.Field1);
```

Or move it out of the join:

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var nullDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
var result = db.TableA.Query()
    .Join(db.TableB).On(db.TableA.KeyField == db.TableB.KeyField)
    .Where((!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, db.TableB.SomeDate) ? db.TableB.SomeDate : nullDate) <= currentDate)
    .Select(db.TableA.Field1, db.TableA.Field2, db.TableB.Field1);
```

What is the data type for `db.TableB.SomeDate`? If `Simple.Data` generates it as a nullable data type (`Nullable<DateTime>`) then you could do:

```
db.TableB.SomeDate.GetValueOrDefault(nullDate) <= currentDate
```

Comment: Hi Cory.  Simple.Data is an ORM that uses dynamic typing, so none of the code starting with `db.TableA` has any compile-time enforcement, and instead is interpreted by the Simple.Data API in order to translate the c# stuff into SQL.  Hence the problem.  If I were using "straight c#", either of your solutions would work fine.  More info on Simple.Data [here](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/wiki)

Comment: @EricP: I did a little research and updated the answer. Underneath the hood, `dynamic` objects are still just objects. You should be able to compare them to `null`. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce is quite useless here.

```
where coalesce(b.SomeDate, '1/1/1900') <= getdate()
```

this essentially means that if b.SomeDate is null then return true since getdate() would never be <= 1/1/1900. You can replace the above with this....

```
where (b.SomeDate is null) or (b.SomeDate <= getdate())
```

this might simplify it a little...

Comment: Hi Sam, your strategy works in this case, though it still doesn't solve the underlying problem of how to use a sql function from simple.data.  Is there a way to award partial credit? :p